# Sitecore Delete the most newly added child

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

In sitecore I want to delete the newly added child.

```
item.DeleteChildren();
```

Delete all the children under `item` But I want to delete the most updated child or the newly added child.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just loop through the items and see which one was created most recently. Something like this:

```csharp
Item newestItem = null;
foreach(Item child in parent.Children)
{
    if (newestItem == null || child.Statistics.Created > newestItem.Statistics.Created)
    {
        newestItem = child;
    }
}

if (newestItem != null)
{
    newestItem.Delete();
}
```

I've used `Item.Statistics.Created` here, but `Item.Statistics.Updated` is also available

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Linq:

```
var newestItem = item.Children.OrderByDescending(child => child.Statistics.Created).FirstOrDefault();

If (newestItem != null)
    newestItem.Delete();
```